# An inconsistency in Julian Grenfell's 'Into Battle'

Tags: meaning, poetry

[Grenfell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_Grenfell)'s First World War poem [*Into Battle*](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/A_treasury_of_war_poetry,_British_and_American_poems_of_the_world_war,_1914-1919/Poets_Militant#Into_Battle) contains this verse :

> The blackbird sings to him: "Brother, brother,
>   If this be the last song you shall sing,
>   Sing well, for you may not sing another;
>    Brother, sing."

*'If'* and *'may'* do not appear to match. If this be the last song, then you will not (not, *'may not'*) sing another.

Is there a puzzle here, an inconsistency, or have I missed the meaning ?

Comment: I don't see why you say *'If' and 'may' do not appear to match.* Fairly obviously ***may not sing = might not sing*** in this context, rather than ***will not be permitted to sing***, so it's structurally the same as *If you're emigrating tomorrow then let's go out for a drink tonight, as we may never meet again*.

Comment: I don't think the parallel quite holds. If this be the last song, then he cannot sing again. If I emigrate, it is not the case that we cannot meet again - only that we might not. 'Might not' could mean 'quite likely will not' : but if this be the last song, he very definitely will not. If 'might not' has a permissive sense and indicates 'will not be allowed to', it is again inappropriate since, as the context implies, he will be dead and beyond permission or prohibition.

Comment: Yes: there's a tautology of the should-be-avoided subset.

Comment: @FF No: the parallel is with 'If you're definitely emigrating by trans-Atlantic liner tomorrow then let's go out for a drink tonight, as you may not be in this country the day after that.'

Comment: I think you're right that "may not sing another" is an understatement. But I'm not surprised; looking for logical consistency in poetry is often futile.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments. Enough material here for me to re-analyse this minor poem.

Answer (score 0):

1. One interpretation might be that the postulating blackbird refers
   first to the last possible song to be sung in *this* world.  Then,
   after death, the poet *may* (or may not) have a chance to sing again
   in the *next* world, if he should happily travel to a musical
   hereafter...
2. Or the bird is just reminding the poet that there's no earthly second
   chance, in which case *"may"* is formally denying permission:

   > **may** modal verb (PERMISSION) ​
   >
   > formal used to ask or give permission:
   >   A reader may borrow up to
   >   six books at any one time.
   >   "May I help myself to some more food?"
   >   "Yes, of course."
   >   Hi, my name's Tiffany. How may I help you?
   >   -- [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/may)

Comment: Hmm.  Perhaps that last song could be a decisive audition?